# Importing LVL made my gradle build fail

Tags: android, gradle

I am pretty new to android development and am just finishing up my first app. I was looking to publish the app on the play store so I was going through the steps of adding licensing to my app. One of the steps is to import the LVL as a library project. I followed the steps [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#add-library) . I am getting the error failed to find target with hash string android-15 in : (file path to sdk). I am also getting a ton of errors in my application now which wont even run. Please help.

Comment: Copy the important content from your link into the question itself. Links rot, and any answers to your question will lose important context for future visitors without the linked steps.